# Heroku and Docker deployed with heroku.yml: How to change image name from 'web'?

Tags: docker, heroku

When I push my Vue.js application to Heroku app with the following `Dockerfile` and `heroku.yml`, it works well.

`bootstrapdebug/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.10.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/bootstrapdebug
WORKDIR /app/bootstrapdebug
RUN apk update && \
    npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve", "--", "--port", "$PORT"]
```

`heroku.yml`:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: bootstrapdebug/Dockerfile
  config:
    NODE_ENV: production
```

But, in `heroku.yml`, once I change the image name from `web` to `vue` (or any different name), the app stuck by raising the following error.
This happens even after when I restore the image name to 'web'.

The last line I get from `heroku logs --tail`:

```
2019-09-23T08:24:20.747248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-anchorage-42007.herokuapp.com request_id=e12af6b0-4139-4bad-8ab8-a07559587d3a fwd="126.112.54.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Why is this happening?

### P.S.

What I did related to making this project

```
vue-cli create bootstrapdebug
cd bootstrapdebug && npm install
```

Comment: you need a web packer for vuejs. why want to rename it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
As I added in the post, 
I use vue-cli to make this project.
Does this mean docker internally use webpacker?
(I am noobs in webpacker and js, sorry if it's the stupid question)
For local development, I use docker-compose.up instead of heroku.yml (with same Dockerfile) and it always works well with any image name. 

The reason I post this question: I named image as 'vue' for the first, and get wanted to deploy to Heroku, so I was curious why it is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your application to respond to HTTP [it must be declared as a `web` process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-web-process-type):

> A Heroku app's `web` process type is special: it's the only process type that can receive external HTTP traffic from Heroku's routers. If your app includes a web server, you should declare it as your app's `web` process.

Aside from `web`, the [`release` process type is also special](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-release-process-type):

> The `release` process type is used to specify the command to run during your app's [release phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase).
>
> ...
>
> No process types besides web and release have special properties.